# API Login call is failing when logging in on different PC's

Tags: wsdl, grant-login-access

I have a user account on a clients Salesforce. These credentials are used on our Web service to connect and upload data to that clients Salesforce account.

However I have found that only my PC will allow the logging in to the API, this is not ideal as I need to have multiple users logged in using the same account and on different PC's in our organisation.

How can I fix this issue?

Here is the exception that is thrown:

```
------------- Top Exception -------------
------- Source -------
System

------- Message -------
Unable to connect to the remote server

------- Stack Trace -------
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream(TransportContext& context)
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()
at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)
at WebONE.SalesForceReference.SforceService.login(String username, String password)
at WebONE.GeneralUtilities.SalesForce.SalesForceHelper.Login()
at WebONE.Service.CampaignService.CreateNewSalesForceLead())


------- Message -------
No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 204.14.234.101:443

------- Stack Trace -------
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Int32 timeout, Exception& exception)
```

Here is a snippet of the Logs from SalesForce

```
Login Time (Australian Eastern Daylight Time)   Source IP   Login Type  Status  Browser Platform    Application Login URL
4/07/2013 12:19 Salesforce.com IP   Remote Access 2.0   Success Unknown Unknown Community   login.salesforce.com
4/07/2013 9:37  203.174.136.182 Application Success Chrome 27   Windows 7   Browser login.salesforce.com
3/07/2013 17:27 203.174.136.182 Application Success Chrome 27   Windows 7   Browser na5.salesforce.com
4/07/2013 12:40 203.174.136.182 Other Apex API  Success .NET Unknown    Unknown N/A
```

I believe that the last record was created when I successfully ran the code locally

Comment: Have you checked the login history for the user after it fails? If you are hitting the right org, it will tell you the reason for the reject. If you see no entry then I'd check that the endpoint is set correctly to either login.salesforce.com or test.salesforce.com and the user name is correct.

Comment: how can I check the login history?

Comment: You may need to get your client to check it for you depending on what permissions they have given you. Login to the web UI of Salesforce and go to Setup (May be under Your Name, depending on which version of setup is enabled.) > Manage Users > Users. Click on your user name and the login history is at the bottom.

Comment: that doesnt show any API access as far as I can tell, just typical login access through the browser. In the code I am using SforceService.login(username, password + securityToken) to gain access. Also I am an Admin user so I should have sufficient access right?

Comment: ah just found the logs you are talking about, interestingly none are appearing when I try to run the code through production, however in as localhost they do appear in the logs. Any ideas why?

Comment: So if nothing is showing then most of the time that means you have the wrong login url or the wrong user name. There could also be something about that computer that is routing traffic incorrectly. Can you login to the web using that computer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The server (salesforce.com) wouldn't actively refuse a connection from legitimate locations, although they do have a blacklist of IPs they won't accept connections from (known spammers). A more likely scenario is the related to the network configuration of the other system. It may be either that a proxy is required, or the firewall on the computer or network needs to be configured correctly. Try using a different account to confirm that it is the application's access, not the user account, that is at fault. Depending on the specific scenario, you'll need to either configure the application to use a proxy, or you'll have to configure the firewall to allow access to that program.

Comment: as mentioned below, it appears to work when I run my code locally, however my machine and the production server run on the same network, so I'm uncertain why it is being refused

Comment: I have updated the error message, it appears as though the problem is happening at the login call.

Answer (score 1):

Clients are not able to gain access because their IP addresses are not listed in "Network Access".

You can handle this in following ways:

1) List Client IPs to "Network Access" in Salesforce Setup.

2) While invoking the service,supply credential as "username" and "password+Security Token" instead of username and password alone.

Comment: I am already providing a security token, the odd thing is that it runs correctly locally, but when using our deployment environment it fails to login, perhaps I do need to add the IP's, should I set it to the publicly visible IP address of our production server?

Comment: You need to add the public IP of the server which is hosting your web service application to Salesforce.

Comment: tried this and it still failed... should I remove the security token and see if that fixes things?

Comment: The security token is instead of whitelisting IP addresses.

Comment: There can be User lockout also because of the previous failure attempts.

Comment: But it continues to run locally, also our production server that hosts the code does is on the same network as my local PC, so why is it running locally but no on the production server?

Comment: @Vignex if Salesforce is blocking this connection would there be logs somewhere, at least that way I can contact the client and say that they need to fix their end...

Comment: @MatthewPigram You've configured your username and password? You said multiple users in your description, it means multiple users will be using same login credentials to access Salesforce?

Comment: @Vignex sorry, yes I found the logs, and yes they are all configured. If that wasnt the case then the code would not be able to run locally. The logs are now in the question description, when run on production I get no logs whatsoever. And yes multiple people will use the same username + password to access Salesforce

Comment: @MatthewPigram No logs in production? then please check the end point configured in the web service invoking Salesforce.

Comment: @Vignex no logs in the actual SalesForce Logs section on the website. Production is our web application we are running in ASP.NET

Comment: @MatthewPigram if there is no logs for the user in login history, then the problem must be in web application side. May be End point is not configured properly, username and password might have typo errors.Moreover from the logs you've attached above says that salesforce (204.14.234.101:443) is refusing your request, which means web-app is sending request which cannot be understood by Salesforce.